# How to group some features in certain thread and run it parallel in KarateDSL

Tags: rest, api, parallel-processing, karate

Now I use karatedsl for testing my REST-API, and I want to run some features parallel..
For example I have 5 feature : feature 1, feature 2, feature 3, feature 4 and feature 5...
How to group those features and run it parallel on certain threads, for example I wanna to run feature 1 and feature 2 in thread 1, feature 3 and 4 in thread 2 and feature 3 in thread 3 ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Till karate 0.8.0 you will be able to parallel run tests in feature level (1 feature per thread).

**Running Features in parallel,**

Here is an example from karate documentation:

```
@CucumberOptions(tags = {"@smoke"})
public class TestParallel {

    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        KarateStats stats = CucumberRunner.parallel(getClass(), 5, "target/surefire-reports");
        assertTrue("scenarios failed", stats.getFailCount() == 0);
    }

}
```

Using this parallel runner you can specify the number of threads you want (*which is 5 in the above example*).

More details on parallel execution here -> [Parallel Execution in Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution)

**Grouping of features:**

You can group feature file using `tags` like `@<tag_name>`,

eg:

```
@smoke
Feature:
    Scenario:
       * print "Smoke"
```

similarly, you can add this tag to all the features that you want to group together for execution.

Now as `CucumberOptions` in your tests mentions which tag to execute karate will run all the tests which are tagged with that name in *parallel*.

More details on Tags: [Tags / Grouping](https://github.com/intuit/karate#cucumber-tags)

So, you can define the grouping by tag and parallel execution by
threads **BUT** you cannot define which thread should run which
feature, IMO it looks meaningless.

> Note:  If you are planning to use `0.9.0`, you
>   will be able to run parallel tests in scenario level (each feature will be breakdown into scenarios and run as 1 scenario per thread )and instead of
>   `CucumberOptions` you have to use `KarateOptions`
>
> More details on karate 0.9.0 changes : [Planned deprecations](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/v0.9.0#planned-deprecations)

Comment: Glad it was helpful ;). What is the benefit or purpose of running series of features in a particular thread? do you have any specific requirement like that?

Comment: @YudistiraSugandi agree with Babu - you should never need to know which thread which `Scenario` is running in which thread, it should be random at run-time. best practice is that one `Scenario` should never depend on another. in 0.9.0 if you want to run all scenarios in a `Feature` in sequence you can, but still they can be on different threads.

Comment: Now I have 2 `features` which each `feature` have 3 `scenario`..
first `scenario` for get bill customer information(named as inquiry), second for create transaction, and third for get transaction detail...
This feature run sequential, you should run inquiry first before you create transaction, but if you do inquiry twice, the second inquiry will replace first inquiry, so you cannot use first inquiry to create transaction...

Comment: @PeterThomas - By the way, in karate version 0.9.0, if I wanna run parallel tests in scenario level, I have to change CucumberOption to KarateOptions in my Runner or test parallel class ?

Comment: @YudistiraSugandi and I already said scenarios should NOT depend on other ones. why are you going on about transactions. read this please: https://github.com/intuit/karate#script-structure